# Taxes on Federal Pension in Puerto Rico Non-Resident?

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, texas, puerto-rico

I'm a federal retiree with a federal pension and I'm a resident of Texas.  I'm only taxed federally on my pension, as Texas does not have a state tax.  I have been offered a year contract in Puerto Rico but will keep my primary residence in Texas, how will income I earn in Puerto Rico from the contract be taxed? Will Puerto Rico tax my federal pension?